# minimumDate equivalent in swiftUI?

Tags: datepicker, swiftui, swiftui-datepicker

I have a `DatePicker` on my app and the user can't select a past date, because I'm creating a notification out of it

How can I implement a `minimumDate` equivalent in SwiftUI?

I tried creating an alert on my save button using “if date < `Date()`, else show alert”, but it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

You can provide a range to `DatePicker`:

```
@State private var date = Date()
let dateRange: ClosedRange<Date> = {
    let calendar = Calendar.current
    let startComponents = DateComponents(year: 2021, month: 1, day: 1)
    let endComponents = DateComponents(year: 2021, month: 12, day: 31, hour: 23, minute: 59, second: 59)
    return calendar.date(from:startComponents)!
        ...
        calendar.date(from:endComponents)!
}()

var body: some View {
    DatePicker(
        "Start Date",
         selection: $date,
         in: dateRange,
         displayedComponents: [.date, .hourAndMinute]
    )
}
```

Source: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/datepicker